# Least value of $\left|2017 z+\frac{1}{2018z}\right|$ for complex $z$ with $|z|\geq 2019$

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima

Let $z=x+iy$ be a complex number with $|z|\geq 2019$. What is the least value of $$\left|2017 z+\frac{1}{2018z}\right| \, ?$$

What I tried: Put $z=re^{i\alpha}$. Then $z^{-1}=\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\alpha}$ and
$$
\left|2017 re^{i\alpha}+\frac{1}{2018r}e^{-i\alpha}\right| \\
= \left |\left(2017r+\frac{1}{2018r}\right)\cos \alpha+\left(2017r-\frac{1}{2018r}\right)\sin \alpha\right| \\
=\sqrt{\left|\left(2017r+\frac{1}{2018r}\right)^2\cos^2\alpha+\left(2017r-\frac{1}{2018r}\right)^2\sin^2\alpha\right|}
$$

Comment: Why don't you use $$z=x+iy$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the triangle inequality
$$
|z+w| \ge |z| - |w|
$$
(with equality if $\overline z w$ is zero or a negative real number) we get
$$
 \left|2017 z+\frac{1}{2018z}\right| \ge 2017 |z|-\frac{1}{2018|z|} 
$$
with equality if $z^2 \le 0$, that is for purely imaginary $z$.
The right-hand side is increasing in $|z|$, so that the minimal value is obtained for the minimal $|z| = 2019$:
$$
\left|2017 z+\frac{1}{2018z}\right| \ge 2017 \cdot 2019 -\frac{1}{2018 \cdot 2019} \, .
$$
Equality holds for $z = \pm 2019 i$.

---

You can also continue with your approach (using polar coordinates) and substitute $\sin^2 \alpha  = 1 - \cos^2 \alpha$:

$$
\sqrt{\left(2017r+\frac{1}{2018r}\right)^2\cos^2\alpha+\left(2017r-\frac{1}{2018r}\right)^2\sin^2\alpha}
= \sqrt{ 4 \frac{2017}{2018}\cos^2\alpha+\left(2017r-\frac{1}{2018r}\right)^2} 
\ge 2017r-\frac{1}{2018r}
$$
where the minimum is attained if $\cos^2 \alpha = 0$. The rest is as above.

Answer (score 1):

Our objective function is given by $$f(x,y)= \left( {\frac {\sqrt {16583822760976}}{2018}\sqrt {{\frac {
1}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}} \left( {x}^{2}+ \left( y+{\frac{1}{2018}} \right) 
^{2} \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+ \left( y-{\frac{1}{2018}} \right) ^{2}
 \right) }}} \right) 
$$ with the condition $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq 2019$$ We get the Minimum for $$x=0,y=-2019$$

Comment: Can you explain *how* you found the minimum?

Comment: By calculus in two variables.

Comment: What about extending your answer with the essential calculations? *“This is the minimum, we get it by calculus”* does not help anybody to understand the problem and the solution.

Comment: Are you anybody? Should i post the whole calculations which i have made?